# Xcode debugger hangs in callback function from JavaScriptCore

Tags: ios, xcode, javascriptcore

## Update

It is fixed in Xcode 8.0

---

## Environment

Xcode 7.3.1, iPhone SE, iOS 9.3.5

## Problem

I bound C function to JavaScript function by `JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback` with JavaScriptCore framework.
If I put breakpoint in this C function,
Xcode debugger hangs when execution position comes here from JavaScript by `JSEvaluateScript`.

- I want to know reason of issue.
- I want to know approach to implement C function which works with breakpoint correctly and is callable from JavaScript environment.

I don't need idea using Objective-C API,
Because I want to share code with iOS and Android.

## Condition

From my experiment, I got these conditions.

- It does not happens in iOS Simulator.
- It does not happens when JS function is calling from `JSObjectCallAsFunction`.
- It happens when JS function is calling from `JSEvaluateScript`.

My opinions by looking call stack in Simulator running is
this issue is from JavaScriptCore's JIT/LLINT embedded assembly.
I guess that these assembly lacks something relates debugging mechanism.
So I worry that there is no solution in programmer on user side of JavaScriptCode.

## Reproducible source code

I packaged small reproducible example in this repository.

https://github.com/omochi/jscore-debugger-hangup

### steps

1. Clone this repository.
2. Open with Xcode.
3. Open `test_main.c`.
4. Put breakpoint at `printf` in `TestNativeFunc` and `JSEvaluateScript` in `TestMain`.
5. Run application.
6. It paused at `printf`.
7. Continue.
8. It paused at `JSEvaluateScript`.
9. Xcode hangs.

If you remove two breakpoints, it run correctly and print two `func` messages.

### code

```
static JSValueRef TestNativeFunc(JSContextRef ctx,
                                 JSObjectRef function,
                                 JSObjectRef thisObject,
                                 size_t argumentCount,
                                 const JSValueRef arguments[],
                                 JSValueRef* exception)
{
    printf("func\n");
    return JSValueMakeNull(ctx);
}    

void TestMain() {
    JSGlobalContextRef context = JSGlobalContextCreate(NULL);

    JSObjectRef func = JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback(context, NULL, &TestNativeFunc);
    JSValueProtect(context, func);

    JSObjectCallAsFunction(context, func, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);    

    JSObjectRef global_object = JSContextGetGlobalObject(context);    

    JSStringRef f_str = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("f");

    JSObjectSetProperty(context, global_object, f_str, func, 0, NULL);

    JSStringRef script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("f();");
    JSEvaluateScript(context, script, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL);

    JSStringRelease(f_str);

    JSValueUnprotect(context, func);
    JSGlobalContextRelease(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Xcode 7.3.1, and it should be fixed in Xcode 8.0.  If you find that it isn't when you get a chance to upgrade to 8.0, please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks your information.
I will download new Xcode and check issue.